# Nextjs Incremental/targeted build for updated component or page to reduce build process time

Tags: npm, next.js, build

NextJS provides the feature to build SSG incrementally with ISR but what if the component used by SSG is changed i.e. a new span tag is added for example. Now every time a new build is needed to generate to update this change.

Is there a better and quicker way to achieve targeted build to reduce the build time process as the number of pages generated with SSG can go up to millions.